# USB Ethernet to my machine rather than RJ45 NIC Cards

Tags: networking, routing, ubuntu-14.04, network-interface, usb-network-adapter

I have a 7 node cluster setup in my organization and they all have dual port Ethernet NICs on them, running Ubuntu 14.04.4. Each machine is connected to two networks at the same time.

**Requirement:**
I want to add 7 more machines but we don’t have the cash to buy 7 more NICs. Is there a way I can use the USB ports on the machines to connect to the network, using a USB router? (Router with USB points instead of RJ45 sockets or something like that.)

**Current Setup:** 
7 Ubuntu machines with two Ethernet ports
1 Cisco Catalyst 2960G-24TC-L Switch with 18 free RJ45 ports.

**Problem:**
Have a switch which can do the networking but the machines don’t have enough NICs.

Comment: A USB Ethernet adapter is still a “NIC”. I doubt they’re that much cheaper, performance could also be a lot worse. Please update your question to include the motherboard model. Also, hardware recommendations are off-topic, I removed that part.

Comment: @Daniel We use a **HP Elitedesk 800G1 SFF**. Datasheet found here [link](http://h71016.www7.hp.com/html/pdfs/HPEliteDeskand_EliteOne_800_G1_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: Can you not [alias the onboard NIC](http://askubuntu.com/questions/585468/how-do-i-add-an-additional-ip-address-to-an-interface-in-ubuntu-14) to be on both networks? Otherwise, you can get gigabit NIC's for around $10-$20, considering you're purchasing 7 HP Elitedesks, that'd be an extra $70-$140 .. USB Ethernet Adapters only operate at the USB speed it's plugged into (usually 2.0, which runs at half the speed of a GigE card) ..

Comment: Indeed, a more in-depth explanation on what exactly “connected to two networks at the same time” entails would be very helpful. Are these networks physically separated? Are they separated by VLANs? Is security a concern?

Comment: @Daniel There are two networks, physically two different ones, separated by VLANs. Security is not a major concern as we are a local cluster and communicate to the Internet via one gateway through proxy and firewalls.

Comment: Thanks for your input @txtechhelp. I have gone ahead and ordered Intel single NICs [luckily got some extra cash ;)].

Comment: So there is no USB 3.0 based network routing.. I wonder why not? Any ideas and opinion. I know I am moving out of the issue. Will like to get some opinion before we close this thread, please.

Answer (score 1):

At our Plant we us something similar to these in a lot of or project PCs.

Of course we had a company Manufacturer ours to the simplest with our logo on them for internal use only.

Our use the Lan9500

[image]

So you want to use one for linux builds I would try this.
[Link To Buy on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AQM8586)

[image]

> Linux
>
> Kernels 3.9 and above have built in driver support.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a switch. A usb router does not work like that. You'd plug those into a PC - the USB ports on routers are meant for mass storage or printers.

Answer (score 0):

USB simply wasn’t made for host-to-host connections. It is not a suitable connection for what you’re doing.

If I understand correctly you have two networks that are running on the same switch, separated only by VLANs. You (somewhat) trust the client PCs.

That makes it possible to use [802.1q VLAN Tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1Q). This means the switch would be set up to tag packets with the VLAN ID before sending them to your client PCs. That way, multiple VLANs can be sent over a single network cable.

This of course also requires client-side configuration that is unfortunately very hard/impossible on Windows. However, it is [very easy on Linux](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/vlan):

```
auto eth1.10
iface eth1.10 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    vlan-raw-device eth1
```

This instructs Ubuntu to create a network interface for VLAN 10 on eth1, using a static IP address.

Be careful to only assign PCs to VLANs they should actually have access to.